# Selecting values from the same dataframe but for different years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of some features and corresponding years. Each value of the feature is listed for different years.  I need to compare the values of a specific year with that 7 years earlier. So basically I need to define a function that will generate two columns one will give me the value of the feature from the table for a specific year and the other one for the same feature but 7 years earlier. How can I do that?

```
feature    year
value1     2001
value1     2008  
vlaue2     1996
```

etc

e.g. I want to compare `value1(2008)` with `value1(2008 - 7)` etc. 
there should also be some conditional statements as year 2000 can't be compared with (2000-7 =1993) because there is no value for the feature for year (1993) for example.

Comment: Can you show your attempt so far?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't been able to generate much. I tried many things but they did not work out. I am still new in python programing. my biggest problem I guess is the conditional statement. so for values measured for 8 years in a row, there is one value I can use to compare with the one 7 years earlier. but for values measured for 5 year only, I can't look back 7 years, because it doesn't exist in the data.

Comment: You're unlikely to get any useful answers with what you've provided. Can you post enough code to create an example dataframe, an attempt  to do the calculationif you have one, and what your expected output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the minimum information you have given, this can be used as a solution:

Let's create a function to get data for both years, if available.

```
def compare(x):
    f1 = df.loc[df['year'] == x, 'feature'].values[0]
    y2 = x - 7
    if y2 in df['year'].unique():
        f2 = df.loc[df['year'] == y2, 'feature'].values[0]
        return (x, f1, y2, f2)
    else:
        pass
```

Apply the function to the year column and assign a new dataframe name.

```
foo = df['year'].apply(compare)
```

Create a dataframe of non-null values in foo:

```
bar = pd.DataFrame(data = list(foo.loc[~foo.isnull()]), columns = ['f1', 'y1', 'f2', 'y2'])
```

This will result in four columns for easy comparison. I understand you were looking for two columns solution but a four column solution with comparative data next to each other would make sense for later usage as well.

Comment: If this was helpful, please accept this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your reply. I tried your code, however I am getting two columns with Nan value in either for each row, which is exactly what is shouldn't do. I guess there is a problem in the conditional statement. is there is another way? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution from what I understand from your question,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'feature': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
        'value': [1, 10, 3, 50],
        'year':[2001, 2002, 2003, 2008]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def compFeature(df, f, y):
    if df[(df.feature == f) & (df.year == (y-7))].year is not None:
        now = df[(df.feature == f) & (df.year == y)].value
        old = df[(df.feature == f) & (df.year == (y-7))].value
        result = np.subtract(now,old)
    else:
        result = np.nan

    return result
```

This is just to get you started.

Comment: Welcome to the site @exan!